# Extra space added to HTML e-mail when sent from Outlook to Gmail

Tags: outlook, gmail, whitespace, html-email

If I open the following HTML e-mail in Gmail or Outlook it renders as it should:

```
<img src="img.png" />
```

However, if I open it in Outlook and then forward it to Gmail, it adds extra garbage HTML that makes the area taller than it should be (the 'p' tag is responsible for the added height - 3px specifically):

```
<p class="MsoNormal">
    <span style="font-size:10.0pt">
        <img src="img.png">
        <u></u>
        <u></u>
     </span>
</p>
```

There are lots of solutions for fixing spacing issues in Gmail, like adding display:block to the image, setting the font-size and line-height to 0, etc. I've tried over a dozen methods and none have worked because of behind the scenes HTML modification that I have no control over - styles and attributes getting stripped, tags with their own properties getting added, etc.

Is there is a work around to allow the original formatting to always be preserved? I will gladly provide any additional details needed, just let me know.

Comment: Forwarding will always cause issues to emails for both rendering and functionality. Generally, adding a forward to friend feature common to most sending systems such as MailChimp is the work around for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fix for this, but there are ways to limit and hide the size of the separation. I'll refer to it as separation, but it is really  the top cell expanding due to Outlook applying the mso-normal p tag. [Here is a related article.](http://commadot.com/gmail-and-p-msonormal/)

Between tables creates a bigger gap (about 15px) than between table rows (2px). It is more complex, but try and put everything that you can't afford separating into one big table. Colspans and rowspans can be complex, but they work if set up correctly.

To hide the separation, wrap all the tables in a master-content table with the bgcolor set. For example, make one big content pane set to white. When sending from Outlook, all your child tables will then move, but the gaps will remain white, stopping unwanted lines appearing in your email body.

A trick for footers - As the last child table of your main white panel, when this separates, it will create a white line underneath it. Either remove the footer table from the main panel or set the cell bgcolor to the same as your email background to hide this separation.

Comment: Hi @John i just have one table with tr tag created in foreach loop and i'm having the issue where space gets added by MsoNormal p tag. Can you advice me a workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change this situation by changing the MsoNormal class

```
 <style>
    td p.MsoNormal {margin: -4px !important}

    /* ou */

    .MsoNormal {
        margin: -4px !important;
    }
 </style>
```